# How do I use proxypass with authentication?

Tags: apache, authentication, proxypass

I'm running Apache 2.4 on Archlinux with Drupal 7. I'm using using smart card authentication into drupal with PKI_authentication module. 
 Note: this is just a test setup I'm using at home trying figure out how to make this work. The production setup is basically the same except for running on Windows 2008 R2.

I also have Apache setup as a reverse proxy to two internal servers using proxypass. I'm trying to limit access to the internal servers to only authorized users. Initially I've tried using "SSLVerifyClient require", which doesn't limit access to authorized users but at least requires them to use a recognized smart card.

The problem is that the two internal servers refer the browser back and forth between them and even open frames with the other server inside. Every time the browser gets redirected to the other server the user has to re-authenticate.

Since drupal uses a session cookie and stores the value for this cookie in a sql database I though I could use mod_session_dbd to verify the users is already authenticated. However the documentation on mod_session_dbd is pretty useless.

Before going on, if someone can suggest a better way to accomplish the above goals I'd very much appreciate it.  I'd rather do this without having to install any new software since the approval process for that is rather lengthy.

Apache's mod_session_dbd documentation (aside from mixing up the database name and session name) in the 'DBD Configuration' block gives an example of:

DBDPrepareSQL "update session set value = %s, expiry = %lld, key = %s where key = %s" updatesession

But it doesn't describe what these variables are. Based on the names it looks like they are referring to the 'key', 'value', & 'expiry' from the cookie. But that doesn't make any sense since everyone that visits the website will have a cookie with exactly the same 'key'(name of the cookie) so I can't update a particular session using just the cookie name, unless this is expected to update every open session to the same 'value', etc. as the current user?

I'm using a basically stock Drupal setup with the following changes (that don't work):

In httpd.conf:

---

```
 LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so 
 LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so 
 LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so 
 LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so 

 DBDriver sqlite3 
 DBDParams "/srv/www/drupalDB/drupal.db" 

 DBDPrepareSQL "select uid from sessions where ssid = %s" selectsession 
 #uis is the userid of current user and ssid is the value in the cookie. 
 #Not sure what selectsession is expected to return. 
 #also tried DBDPrepareSQL "select ssid from sessions where ssid = %s" selectsession, but that didn't work either 
 #Not using deletesession, insertsession, etc at this time since I don't want to mess up the database
```

---

### in httpd-ssl.conf:

```
 <Location /site1> 
 # SSLRequireSSL 
 AuthType Basic 
 AuthName "Internal" 
 Session On 
 SessionDBDCookieName SSESS0ea0798a41d3d84e7bbc0af79a07cd87 
 SessionDBDPerUser On 
 SessionDBDSelectLabel selectsession 
 Require valid-user 
 ErrorDocument 401 /sites/default/misc/pki_authentication/index.php 

 </Location> 
 ProxyPass /site1 http://192.168.0.3/site1 
 ProxyPassReverse /site1 http://192.168.0.3/site1
```

---

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this on your internal servers - it depends on what they are - but with JBOSS and Tomcat, we set the stickysession and then in the JBOSS/Tomcat config, we give them a route name. This prevents the balancer from swapping nodes back and forth and forcing re-authentication all the time.

In Apache (httpd.conf):

```
# ***** HA CONFIGURATION FOR JBOSS & TOMCAT WEB APPLICATIONS *** SSL BACKEND

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify On
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off


SSLProxyVerifyDepth 2
SSLProxyCACertificateFile /path/to/server-ca.crt

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember https://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:XXX1 route=node1 loadfactor=1 ping=10 ttl=600
BalancerMember https://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:XXX2 route=node2 loadfactor=1 ping=10 ttl=600
</Proxy>

ProxyTimeout 300
ProxyStatus On
```

Then in Tomcat: (on the secondary server it's node2)

```
  <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="node1">
```

I don't have access to the JBOSS configuration right now, but they do something similar.